# How should I map tvOS AppDelegate's applicationWillEnterForeground to a javascript function?

Tags: javascript, swift, tvos, apple-tv, tvml

I'm following Apple's Sample project for [Playing Media in a Client-Server App](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/tvmljs/playing_media_in_a_client-server_app).

```
func executeRemoteMethod(_ methodName: String, completion: @escaping (Bool) -> Void) {
    appController?.evaluate(inJavaScriptContext: { (context: JSContext) in
        let appObject : JSValue = context.objectForKeyedSubscript("App")

        if appObject.hasProperty(methodName) {
            appObject.invokeMethod(methodName, withArguments: [])
        }
        }, completion: completion)
}
```

The method is getting called during Application lifecycle events like this:

```
func applicationWillEnterForeground(_ application: UIApplication) {

    executeRemoteMethod("onWillEnterForeground", completion: { (success: Bool) in
        // ...
    })
}
```

I'm wondering how it's working. Is this so that the native iOS codebase can communicate the lifecycle event to the Javascript code? When I put a breakpoint I see `executeRemoteMethod` function getting called. But I don't think it's actually doing anything. How can I map it to a js function? Do I have to create a new js file or just create a new function in my `application.js` file?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks to reading this [tutorial](https://tommyb.com/blog/making-apple-tv-apps-part-10-creating-our-first-tvml-based-tvos-app/). I learned:

> In the block beginning, we first get a reference to our
>   JavaScript **“App” object**. Then, we test the existence of a property
>   with the method name that was passed to us. If it exists, we
>   invoke the method. Although the current implementation
>   doesn’t pass arguments to the method, we could modify it to do that as
>   well if needed. Finally, the completion block that was passed to us is
>   executed when the execution of the JavaScript method has been
>   completed That similar to how the function is already written
>   inside `application.js`:

In its tutorial the `application.js` looks like this:

```
App.onLaunch = function(options) {
    var alert = createAlert("Hello World!", "Welcome to tvOS");
    navigationDocument.pushDocument(alert);
}

App.onWillResignActive = function() {
}

App.onDidEnterBackground = function() {
}

App.onWillEnterForeground = function() {
}

App.onDidBecomeActive = function() {
}

App.onWillTerminate = function() {
}

var createAlert = function(title, description) {
    var alertString = `<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" ?>
        <document>
          <alertTemplate>
            <title>${title}</title>
            <description>${description}</description>
          </alertTemplate>
        </document>`

    var parser = new DOMParser();

    var alertDoc = parser.parseFromString(alertString, "application/xml");

    return alertDoc
}
```

---

As a result I just have to add the following inside `application.js` then it will get called upon AppDelegates's `WillEnterForeGround` callback.

```
App.onWillEnterForeground = function(options) {
    console.log("something")
}
```